# Complex multiplication and symetry

Tags: complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry

The complex multiplication is a similar map, i.e. for all $w,z_1,z_2\in \mathbb{C}$ we have
 $$|w||z_1 - z_2|= |wz_1-wz_2|.$$ 
Therefore $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}, f(z):=\zeta\bar\zeta^{-1}\bar{z}$ for any nonzero $\zeta\in\Bbb{C}$ must also be a isometry and since the only fixed points of $f$ are $\{a\zeta:a\in\mathbb{R}\}$, $f$ must be the the map which provides the point $z'$ which is symmetrical to $z$ on the $a\zeta$-axis.

Can somebody please explain me the last implication? That given a isometry on a plane and a set of fixed points implicates a symetry-map? I have tried to understand this Statement by drawing upon elementar-geometry books, but my linear Algebra skills are not sufficient enough. That's why I would prefer a intuitive explaination over a maybe rigorous proof in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $\zeta$ here? If $a\zeta,a\in\Bbb{R}$ and $a\neq0$ then $\zeta\in\Bbb{R}$ and so $f$ is simply complex conjugation.

Comment: $\zeta$ is a complex number

Comment: So then either $\zeta\in\Bbb{R}$ or $a=0$. Your question is *very* unclear.

Comment: Given the complex plane, you choose a $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}$, you draw a line intersecting $0$ to $\zeta$ and define the line as $\zeta$-axis. You have the function f and you put in a complex number z. You observe that if the complex number is $\zeta$ , $f(\zeta)=\zeta\bar\zeta^{-1}\bar{\zeta}= \zeta$, so if you choose $\zeta = z, f$ behaves like the identity function. If your Input is $a\zeta$ then $f(a\zeta) = (a\zeta)$ thus for values of $a\zeta,a\in \mathbb{R}$ you get the identity back otherwise the result is different and due to f being isometric, $f$ must be the symetrical projection.

Comment: Maybe my notes of the lecture are also false but that was just the context of my Question. My Question was "Does given a isometry on a plane and a set of fixed points implicates a symetry-map?"

Comment: I understand your question now. The implication is true, it is simply a statement about isometries.

Comment: I have edited your question in hopes of making it clearer. Feel free to rollback if my edits do not reflect (pun intended) your intentions. Also, your original phrasing implied that the zero map is an isometry, which it isn't.

Comment: thank you very much, the edit is very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose a plane isometry $f$ fixes a line through the origin $L$ pointwise. Let $p,q\in L$ be two distinct points. For every point $z$ in the plane we have
$$|p-z|=|f(p)-f(z)|=|p-f(z)|
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
|q-z|=|f(q)-f(z)|=|q-f(z)|.$$
Geometrically this means that if we draw two circles centered at $p$ and $q$ and both passing through $z$, they also both pass through $f(z)$, as in the picture:

[image: [Picture in the making]]

This tells us that either $f(z)=z$, or $f(z)$ is the reflection of $z$ in the line $L$. As this is true for every $z$, and $f$ is an isometry, it follows (prove this!) that $f$ is either the identity or the reflection in the line $L$.

Comment: I don't know how to prove it properly but because (I use the bar Notation to describe a track) $|\overline{zp}| = |\overline{f(z)p}|$ we have an isosceles triangle $zpf(z)$ therefor the hight of the triangle must be perpendicular to $\overline{zf(z)}$ showing that f(z) is the reflection or the triangle is deformed because $|\overline{zf(z)}|=0$ and therefore f must be the identity then.